# How to start Outlook programmatically (C#) without showing session logon box?

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm in console app. This only line starts Outlook and shows logon dialog box for me:

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
```

All tutorials I found use the code like this:

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);
```

So they assume just creating an Outlook.Application instance doesn't open the dialog, you need to call Logon first. But in my case I'm getting this dialog right at the moment when Outlook.Application instance is created.

outlook.exe process isn't running at the moment when I start the app.

In the dialog, there is a checkbox "Use the selected configuration by default" (I translated the text to English, my Outlook is in different language). Even if I tick this checkbox, next time I see the dialog again.

What can I do to fix that and open Outlook without this box? I'm using Outlook 2010 64-bit.

Comment: Have you ever worked this out?  I'm having the same issue 5+ years later.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember. Most likely, I gave up on that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't have the default profile chosen in the Mail Options in Windows. So, you will get the dialog anyway. Also the following line of code is used in the code:

```
 ns.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);
```

It doesn't specify any profile to log in. See [Where is Outlook Mail Setup in Control Panel?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/04/28/where-is-outlook-mail-setup-in-control-panel/) where you can choose the default and set up new profiles.

Comment: No, in this dialog in control panel it has "use configuration" radio-button selected and "Outlook" profile is selected by default. I guess if no default profile was specified, I'd see this dialog whenever I start Outlook. But I see it only when I start it programmatically.